# Prism's RegionManager view switching performance

Tags: wpf, performance, prism

I'm performance profiling a WPF application written using the PRISM library.
Navigating from one view to another view is particulary slow in this application, especially when navigating away from a "heavy" view.
Note that:

- views are cached and not re-constructed when navigating back & forth 
  (a consequence of PRISM keeping all views in the SingleActiveRegion)
- I understand that constructing a view can be slow the first time due to xaml parsing, JIT'ing, .. BUT this question is about navigation remaining slow, even AFTER opening a view for the first time

Using the PRISM library, regions are generally implemented on a ContentControl, like:

```
<ContentControl regions:RegionManager.RegionName="MAIN" />
```

As a consequence, switching a view in the MAIN region will update the "Content" of this ContentControl (as can be seen from [the source code](https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism/blob/a60d38013c02b60807e9287db9ba7f7506af0e84/Source/Wpf/Prism.Wpf/Regions/ContentControlRegionAdapter.cs)).
Setting & switching UI elements as the "Content" of a ContentControl has performance side effects (see [this blogpost](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/tomershamam/2009/09/11/wpf-performance-sweets-contentcontrolcontent-null/)).

To overcome this behavior, I implemented a custom [RegionAdapterBase](https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism/blob/a60d38013c02b60807e9287db9ba7f7506af0e84/Source/Wpf/Prism.Wpf/Regions/ContentControlRegionAdapter.cs) ([CachingGridRegionAdapter.cs](https://gist.github.com/koenj/ff85dfc2ea13be64cb1094bd2a702faa)) for a Grid, which basically adds all views being navigated as Children, and hides all non-active views.

The performance gains are tremendous; navigating from one view to another view is instant now. 
Question: are there any downsides to this approach?

- memory-wise, I don't see an issue since all views were kept in memory by PRISM anyway
- is there a downside to having a big visual tree, with many parts having Visibility = Collapsed?

If there are any other ways to overcome this problem, please let me know.

Thanks for your time,

Koen

Comment: I'm currently experiencing the same issue as you. Ironically, the issue is only problematic on Microsoft Surface tablets and it takes up to 10s to unload a heavy view. I'm reluctant to replace the `ContentControl` with an `ItemsControl` with Collapsed items. We have some global functionality that traverses the Visual Tree (eg to move fields based on preferences) which would need to be refactored. Isn't there any way to improve performance on unloading Views in a `ContentControl`?