# How to improve ContentControl unloading performance

Tags: c#, wpf

I am developing a WPF application using MVVM with the ViewModel-First approach. A common way for page navigation in ViewModel-First is setting a ViewModel as the Content of a ContentControl. By using DataTemplates, the correct View is rendered.

Replacing the ContentControls Content can cause **performance issues when the View to replace has a complex Visual Tree**. It needs to be unloaded which means that the entire tree is recursively cleaned. This is explained in detail in this [blogpost](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/tomershamam/2009/09/11/wpf-performance-sweets-contentcontrolcontent-null/). I have noticed this is device dependent but can go up to 10 seconds to unload a complex page.

I have currently found 2 solutions to this problem:

1. Use **smaller Views** or use controls with virtualization: by splitting a View into different pages or using a TabControl, the problem can be solved (partly). However the question remains, when does a View become too large?
2. Use an **ItemsControl** which contains all previous pages, so unloading is never necessary. This solution is suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41937963/prisms-regionmanager-view-switching-performance) and [here](http://vslepakov.blogspot.be/2014/09/navigate-faster-with-prism-and-wpf.html). This solution might have disadvantages with code that traverses the Visual and Logic tree and might cause other performance issues since all previous views are stored in memory.

Can the performance of unloading the ContentControl be improved without resulting to one of the mentioned solutions?

Comment: I am using the 2. choice without problems. WPF Views can take a lot of memory though. Sometimes clearing the list of  ViewModels the ItemsControl bound to, and calling GC (or wait for it) solves that.

Comment: 10 seconds... it's a lot! Try profiling which is the most time consuming operation, or remove parts of the UI, and check how it influences loading/unloading time. I had a really serious issue of that kind once, and found that one small icon had zillion paths with opacity...